# Multiple checkbox filtering javascript and Django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I am trying to use check boxes in order to filter my results at an html page. Through a django view a pass my data in a list, and then through a loop like this:

```
</div>
{% for r in rows %}
    <div class="res_show">
        <div class="btitle">
        <a href="/show_business/{{r.b_id}}/"><p style="text-align:left"><b>{{r.name}}</b></p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="baddress">
        <p>{{r.address}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="reviewstar">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="/apply_review/{{r.b_id}}/"><p style="text-align:left"><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> {{r.stars}} ({{r.r_count}})</p></a>
        {% else %}
            <p style="text-align:left"><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> {{r.stars}} ({{r.r_count}})</p>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="b_category">
            <p style="text-align: left"> <b>{{r.category}}</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="diraddress">
        <a href="/show_directions/{{r.id}}/"><p style="text-align:left">{{r.duration}}'     {{r.distance}} χλμ <b>{{r.open}}</b></p></a>
        </div>
        <hr style="border:3px solid #333333">
    </div>
```

i want to use this class for filtering:

```
<div class="b_category">
        <p style="text-align: left"> <b>{{r.category}}</b></p>
    </div>
```

Category has 4 possible values: cafe, bar, nigh_club, reastaurant

I have found the following code but i can't figure out what i should change in order to work in my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/x1av5809/

Category may contain more tha one values seperated by comma, for example
bar or cafe, bar
An example of use would be choosing the bar check box and showing only results that contain category bar. I i choose both bar and cafe check boxes i should show results that contain bar or cafe category
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through your checked checkboxes and then using `b:contains..` check the element have that checked values or not depending on this hide/show divs .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("input[name='filterStatus']").change(function() {
  //check if the checkbox checked length is > 0
  if ($("input[name='filterStatus']:checked").length > 0) {
    $(".res_show").hide() //hide all divs 
    $("input[name='filterStatus']:checked").each(function() {
      var values = $(this).val() //get valeu of checked checkboxess
      $(".b_category  b:contains(" + values + ")").closest(".res_show").show() //show same
    })
  } else {
    $(".res_show").show()
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="b_category">
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="Cafe" /><label>Cafe</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="Restaurant" /><label>Restaurant</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="Bar" /><label>Bar</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="Night club" /><label>Night club</label>
</div>
<div class="res_show">
  <div class="btitle">
    <a href="/show_business/{{r.b_id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left"><b>some1</b></p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="baddress">
    <p>123,abc</p>
  </div>
  <div class="reviewstar">
    <a href="/apply_review/{{r.b_id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left"><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 5 </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="b_category">
    <p style="text-align: left"> <b>Cafe</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="diraddress">
    <a href="/show_directions/{{r.id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left">123 χλμ <b>12:30</b></p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <hr style="border:3px solid #333333">
</div>
<div class="res_show">
  <div class="btitle">
    <a href="/show_business/{{r.b_id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left"><b>somethins</b></p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="baddress">
    <p>123,abc</p>
  </div>
  <div class="reviewstar">
    <a href="/apply_review/{{r.b_id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left"><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 5 </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="b_category">
    <p style="text-align: left"> <b>Night club</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="diraddress">
    <a href="/show_directions/{{r.id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left">123 χλμ <b>12:30</b></p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <hr style="border:3px solid #333333">
</div>
<div class="res_show">
  <div class="btitle">
    <a href="/show_business/{{r.b_id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left"><b>some4</b></p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="baddress">
    <p>123,abc</p>
  </div>
  <div class="reviewstar">
    <a href="/apply_review/{{r.b_id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left"><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 5 </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="b_category">
    <p style="text-align: left"> <b>Bar</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="diraddress">
    <a href="/show_directions/{{r.id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left">123 χλμ <b>12:30</b></p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <hr style="border:3px solid #333333">
</div>
<div class="res_show">
  <div class="btitle">
    <a href="/show_business/{{r.b_id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left"><b>somes</b></p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="baddress">
    <p>123,abc</p>
  </div>
  <div class="reviewstar">
    <a href="/apply_review/{{r.b_id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left"><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 5 </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="b_category">
    <p style="text-align: left"> <b>Cafe</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="diraddress">
    <a href="/show_directions/{{r.id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left">123 χλμ <b>12:30</b></p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <hr style="border:3px solid #333333">
</div>
<div class="res_show">
  <div class="btitle">
    <a href="/show_business/{{r.b_id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left"><b>somes</b></p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="baddress">
    <p>123,abc</p>
  </div>
  <div class="reviewstar">
    <a href="/apply_review/{{r.b_id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left"><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 5 </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="b_category">
    <p style="text-align: left"> <b>Restaurant</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="diraddress">
    <a href="/show_directions/{{r.id}}/">
      <p style="text-align:left">123 χλμ <b>12:30</b></p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <hr style="border:3px solid #333333">
</div>
```

Comment: This works pertfect and thank you for that. One more question: how could i use AND logical operator like this:
$(".b_category  b:contains(" + values + ")" && ".slidecontainer  b:contains(" + values2 + ")").closest(".res_show").show() so that i can use 2 subclasses of class res_show.
In other words i want to use 2 filters at the same time, but both of them must be fullfied in order to show that particular class!

Comment: then you need to use different logic for same i.e : get contain of `b_category b` tag and check if the `.indexOf(values) > -1` and same for other div if both return true show required divs . Try at your end and then let me know :)

Comment: I am sorryy but i don't understand exactly what do you mean. I  haven't much experience at front end, and that's the Reason i have newbie questions

Comment: If you could provide me an example would help me a lot!

Comment: Yes , the only difference is that i added one hidden div, with class "slidecontainer". Possible values are "0", "1", "2" and "3", "4". I want to use both divs to filter my results. Take a look here:     http://jsfiddle.net/jmg4o238/    
It work but only for one filter at a time. If both check box and slidecontainer are active i want to user AND logical operator. For example if cafe checked and price range is 3 , I want to keep only the divs that have: b_category b -> cafe && (AND) slidecontainer b ->3

Comment: Ok let me try on my end .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229983/discussion-between-swati-and-nikos-tzagkarakis).